# Am I doing something wrong with the fetch api or is it the app I'm currently using

Tags: javascript, fetch-api

I'm new to using `fetch()`, so there's a chance that I'm doing something wrong, but there's also the possibility that the app I'm currently using on the iPad just doesn't support the fetch api. What I'm wondering is if I've made a mistake, or if it's more likely that the app doesn't support `fetch()`?

Here's the code:

```
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
  let long;
  let lat;
  let temperatureDegree = document.querySelector(".temperature-degree");
  let locationTimezone = document.querySelector(".location-timezone");

  if(navigator.geolocation){
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(position => {
      long = position.coords.longitude;
      lat = position.coords.latitude;

      const proxy = "https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/";
      const api = `${proxy}https://api.darksky.net/forecast/***PERSONAL KEY GOES HERE***/${lat},${long}`;

      fetch(api)
       .then(response => {
          return response.json();
       });
       .then(data => {
        // Setting DOM Elements from API
        locationTimezone.textContent = data.timezone;
        temperatureDegree.textContent = data.currently.temperature;
       });
    });
  };
});
```

I've removed my key for the API to ask the question, but when running the code, I obviously have it in there.

Also, it's worth pointing out that because I'm on an iPad for the time being, that I don't have access to a console to see any errors (if there are any) so I can't provide any more details on that.

Comment: Any errors? Are you sure the geolocation is succeeding?

Comment: What goes wrong? What app?

Comment: See comments above looking for more information. In the meantime, you can see if you need a fetch polyfill: https://caniuse.com/#search=fetch, and you can add a polyfill if necessary: https://www.npmjs.com/package/whatwg-fetch

Comment: An app that doesn't let you debug whatsoever sounds like an exceedingly poor development environment. I don't think you'll find much success with absolutely no ability to detect even simple but difficult to spot syntax errors, let alone potentially more confounding logical errors...

Comment: Always have your devtools open in your browser.  You'll notice some errors in your console.

Comment: @Klaycon it's not something I make a habit out of, it's just for a few days while I wait to get a new laptop. The question was more of a "I'm aware of what could be wrong but is there a chance it's something else" kind of question!

Comment: When constructing the string const `api`, it seems to wind up as `https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/ *https://* api.darksky.net/forecast/`, might that have an effect?

Answer (score 3):

I've noticed one error:

```
});
.then(data => {
```

should not include the semicolon:

```
})
.then(data => {
```

For additional examples: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fetch_API/Using_Fetch

Comment: This doesn't seem to fix the issue completely, but it's a step in the right direction so thank you!